# Fuzzy phrase similarity in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, search, fuzzy-search

Using SQL Server, how should I perform a fuzzy ranked search across all rows in a large table for similarity to a long phrase on one column?

In other words, if my data looks like this:

| Id | Data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog |
| 2 | the quick brown cat jumps over the lazy frog |
| 3 | the lazy quick brown frog jumps over the cat |
| 4 | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet |

And I search for "the quick brown ox jumps over a lazy dog", I want results that roughly resemble:

| Id | Score |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 95 |
| 2 | 80 |
| 3 | 40 |
| 4 | 0 |

Actual data would have more rows and longer phrases.

Obviously I don't want an exact string match, so using `LIKE` or `CONTAINS` apparently wouldn't work.

Word order matters, so searching each word individually would not work either.

Full-text indices and sounds-like indices seem like they're only useful for sub-string similarity, so I haven't seen a way to apply that to phrase similarity. For example, how could you query this in a way that gives a decent score to a similar phrase that has missing or added words?

I've tested using edit distance (Lavenshtein, Jaro-Winkler, etc), but it's far too slow over a large set of long strings. One query takes several minutes. It sounds like it should only be used on smaller data, so I think a different kind of approach is needed here.

I've seen TFIDF and cosine similarity mentioned, but I'm not sure whether that's the right thing to use here, or how it might be implemented on SQL Server.

Also, CLR support is limited since we're using SQL Server on Linux. It looks like it's allowed as long as it doesn't require unsafe or external permissions.

Comment: SQL Server's Full-Text Index feature is more capable than you think, but requires tinkering and familiarity with its embedded search string syntax - but as an alternative have you considered using something like Lucene? (I use a .NET port of Lucene in many of my projects which works smoothly)

Comment: Have you had a look at SOUNDEX and DIFFERENCE functions in SQL Server?

Comment: This might also be of use to you;
https://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/roll-your-own-fuzzy-match-grouping-jaro-winkler-t-sql

Comment: How did you get the score of 95 here? What score would you expect from a phrase like `'over the lazy dog'`?

Comment: Difference looks like it still would be word-specific, so it probably wouldn't work well for phrases. 

The numbers are made up; it's 95 (not 100) because it says "ox", not "fox".

Comment: *"so it probably wouldn't work well for phrases."* But that is *exactly* what you have given us as sample data, so if you think that comparing the phrase `'over the lazy dog''` to the phrase `'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'` "wouldnt' work well" because they are phrases then should we be assuming you actually want to compare words, not phrases?

Comment: Fuzzy phrase comparisons are what I want, but trying to match `the fox jumps over the dog` to `the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog` using SOUNDEX sounds like it would be a disaster. It seems like it would only work with similar substrings, like the example you picked, but wouldn't work at all for word deletions/insertions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A relative fast method to quickly find the best matching string using fuzzy matching logic can be based on counting matching 3-grams in the strings.

It may utilize pre-built sql functions and indexed table which should speed up the search. In particular it does not have to check distance from search string to every string in the data set.

First, for convenience, create a table function that breaks strings into 3-letter tokens.

```
drop function dbo.get_triplets;
go
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.get_triplets
(   
    @data varchar(1000)
)
RETURNS TABLE AS RETURN 
(
    WITH Nums AS
    (
      SELECT n = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [object_id])  FROM sys.all_objects 
    )
    select triplet,count(*) c, len(@data)-2 triplet_count
    from (
        select SUBSTRING(@data,n,3) triplet
        from (select top (len(@data)-2) n from nums) n
    ) triplets
    group by triplet
)
GO
```

Create a string dataset

```
drop table if exists #data;
select * into #data
from (
values
(1, 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),
(2, 'the quick brown cat jumps over the lazy frog'),
(3, 'the lazy quick brown frog jumps over the cat'),
(4, 'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet')
) a(id,data);
```

Create an indexed table of 3-letter tokens

```
drop table if exists #triplets;
select id,triplet,c,triplet_count data_triplet_count 
into #triplets
from #data d
cross apply dbo.get_triplets(d.data);

CREATE unique CLUSTERED INDEX IX_triplet_index ON #triplets(triplet,id);
```

Then I would expect an efficient fuzzy search of a match to a given string using query similar to

```
declare @string_to_search varchar(1000) = 'the quick brown ox jumps over a lazy dog';

select  matched.*,d.data,
cast(
cast(matched_triplets as float)
/
cast(case when data_triplet_count>string_triplet_count 
          then data_triplet_count 
          else string_triplet_count
          end as float) 
as decimal(4,3)) score 
from (
    select id,sum(case when a.c<b.c then a.c else b.c end) matched_triplets,
    max(a.data_triplet_count) data_triplet_count,
    max(b.triplet_count) string_triplet_count
    from #triplets a
    join dbo.get_triplets(@string_to_search) b
    on a.triplet = b.triplet
    group by id
) matched
join #data d
on d.id = matched.id;
```

Comment: This is much closer to the kind of thing I'm looking for.

On our real data I've been getting some oddly high scores on some items, but I think it's due to weird redundancies in some of the phrases, where repeated phrases are increasing the score. 

I think I can probably make some tweaks to do some pre-processing, or maybe to penalize the score for too many occurrences of a triplet.

Comment: if you are using longer strings with high occurrence of triplet matched, use 4-letter tokens instead.

Answer (score 2):

There are many methods and algorithms that perform fuzzy string comparison.

In my system I use a CLR function that calculates a [Jaro–Winkler distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jaro%E2%80%93Winkler_distance). I use it when a user tries to create a new company. Before creating a new entry I calculate the Jaro–Winkler distance between a new company name and all existing companies in the database to see if it already exists and allow for some mistypes and slightly different spelling.

I show few top matches to the user hoping that they would not create duplicates.

This is how it works for your example:

```sql
DECLARE @T TABLE (id int, val VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO @T VALUES
(1,  'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),
(2,  'the quick brown cat jumps over the lazy frog'),
(3,  'the lazy quick brown frog jumps over the cat'),
(4,  'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet'),
(12, 'the quick brown ox jumps over the lazy dog'),
(13, 'the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog'),
(14, 'the quick brown ox jumps over a lazy dog')
;

SELECT
    T.*
    ,dbo.StringSimilarityJaroWinkler(T.val, 
        'the quick brown ox jumps over a lazy dog') AS dist
FROM @T AS T
ORDER BY dist desc
;
```

```
+----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| id |                     val                      |       dist        |
+----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
| 14 | the quick brown ox jumps over a lazy dog     | 1                 |
| 13 | the quick brown fox jumps over a lazy dog    | 0.995121951219512 |
| 12 | the quick brown ox jumps over the lazy dog   | 0.975586080586081 |
|  1 | the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog  | 0.971267143709004 |
|  2 | the quick brown cat jumps over the lazy frog | 0.931560196560197 |
|  3 | the lazy quick brown frog jumps over the cat | 0.836212121212121 |
|  4 | lorem ipsum dolor sit amet                   | 0.584472934472934 |
+----+----------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

Here is a C# code for the CLR function:

```cs
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    /*
    The Winkler modification will not be applied unless the percent match
    was at or above the WeightThreshold percent without the modification.
    Winkler's paper used a default value of 0.7
    */
    private static readonly double m_dWeightThreshold = 0.7;

    /*
    Size of the prefix to be concidered by the Winkler modification.
    Winkler's paper used a default value of 4
    */
    private static readonly int m_iNumChars = 4;

    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction(DataAccess = DataAccessKind.None, SystemDataAccess = SystemDataAccessKind.None, IsDeterministic = true, IsPrecise = true)]
    public static SqlDouble StringSimilarityJaroWinkler(SqlString string1, SqlString string2)
    {
        if (string1.IsNull || string2.IsNull)
        {
            return 0.0;
        }

        return GetStringSimilarityJaroWinkler(string1.Value, string2.Value);
    }

    private static double GetStringSimilarityJaroWinkler(string string1, string string2)
    {
        int iLen1 = string1.Length;
        int iLen2 = string2.Length;
        if (iLen1 == 0)
        {
            return iLen2 == 0 ? 1.0 : 0.0;
        }

        int iSearchRange = Math.Max(0, Math.Max(iLen1, iLen2) / 2 - 1);

        bool[] Matched1 = new bool[iLen1];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matched1.Length; ++i)
        {
            Matched1[i] = false;
        }
        bool[] Matched2 = new bool[iLen2];
        for (int i = 0; i < Matched2.Length; ++i)
        {
            Matched2[i] = false;
        }

        int iNumCommon = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iLen1; ++i)
        {
            int iStart = Math.Max(0, i - iSearchRange);
            int iEnd = Math.Min(i + iSearchRange + 1, iLen2);
            for (int j = iStart; j < iEnd; ++j)
            {
                if (Matched2[j]) continue;
                if (string1[i] != string2[j]) continue;

                Matched1[i] = true;
                Matched2[j] = true;
                ++iNumCommon;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (iNumCommon == 0) return 0.0;

        int iNumHalfTransposed = 0;
        int k = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < iLen1; ++i)
        {
            if (!Matched1[i]) continue;
            while (!Matched2[k])
            {
                ++k;
            }
            if (string1[i] != string2[k])
            {
                ++iNumHalfTransposed;
            }
            ++k;
            // even though length of Matched1 and Matched2 can be different,
            // number of elements with true flag is the same in both arrays
            // so, k will never go outside the array boundary
        }
        int iNumTransposed = iNumHalfTransposed / 2;

        double dWeight =
            (
                (double)iNumCommon / (double)iLen1 +
                (double)iNumCommon / (double)iLen2 +
                (double)(iNumCommon - iNumTransposed) / (double)iNumCommon
            ) / 3.0;

        if (dWeight > m_dWeightThreshold)
        {
            int iComparisonLength = Math.Min(m_iNumChars, Math.Min(iLen1, iLen2));
            int iCommonChars = 0;
            while (iCommonChars < iComparisonLength && string1[iCommonChars] == string2[iCommonChars])
            {
                ++iCommonChars;
            }
            dWeight = dWeight + 0.1 * iCommonChars * (1.0 - dWeight);
        }
        return dWeight;
    }

};
```

Comment: This looks very similar to the Lavenshtein distance I mentioned in the question, which I've heard has terrible performance on large strings on large tables.

Comment: At first you should find an algorithm that produces correct results. There is no point having a program that works really fast, but produces useless numbers. You need to try several algorithms on your real data and see for yourself which methods give you reasonable results. Only you can do it, because only you know your data. After that you can think about their performance.

Comment: Once it comes to performance, usually in databases the bottleneck is the disk, not CPU. To find the best match the engine has to read the whole table from the disk regardless of the comparison function. So, unless the comparison function is extremely slow, e.g. `O(n!)` you should not see significant difference in performance of different algorithms.

Comment: I never analysed the complexity of this implementation of the Jaro-Winkler that I use, but it looks like `O(n*n)`.

Comment: I found a pure SQL implementation of the algorithm and test it on a larger data set, and a single query took several minutes, which is far too slow. The results weren't great on the larger data either, which I assume is because longer strings means more possibilities for incorrect matches. It's possible the CLR version is faster, but at this point it seems like a different approach is called for.

Answer (score 1):

Use the FUNCTION F_INFERENCE_BASIQUE I wrote about that...

https://sqlpro.developpez.com/cours/sql/comparaisons-motifs/#LVI

Demo :

```
CREATE TABLE T_TEST (id int, val VARCHAR(256));
INSERT INTO T_TEST VALUES
(1,     'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog'),
(2,     'the quick brown cat jumps over the lazy frog'),
(3,     'the lazy quick brown frog jumps over the cat'),
(4,     'lorem ipsum dolor sit amet');

SELECT id, 100.0 * dbo.F_INFERENCE_BASIQUE(val, 'the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog') 
       / LEN('the quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog') AS PERCENT_MATCH
FROM   T_TEST

id          PERCENT_MATCH
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           100.000000000000
2           46.511627906976
3           81.395348837209
4           6.976744186046
```

You can adapt the code for you own convenience, as an example in eliminatig the two ways comparizon with only the one way... In this case the match indice is :

```
id          PERCENT_MATCH
----------- ---------------------------------------
1           100.000000000000
2           46.511627906976
3           25.581395348837
4           4.651162790697
```

Wich is nearly close to your demand !

Comment: The link is in French, but it sounds like this is very similar to Lavenshtein, but trying to get better performance with less accuracy? I'll take a look.

Comment: It is quicker than jaroWinkler and Levenshtein

Comment: I tested this on a large data set, and it took quite a long time (~10 seconds) and the results were fairly poor, since even an exact match had the exact same score as dozens of other completely different rows. I tried both the two-way and one-way comparisons.

Comment: I assume it's not working because when the strings get long enough, there's always something later that it can find to match on, so there's simply too many matches, and it's not penalizing the gaps between matches enough.

Comment: So it looks like this use case probably needs some entirely different kind of approach.